# PHP / MySql Insert on GoDaddy

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm using heredocs for a php/mysql insert statement on godaddy.  When the function is called the page refreshes correctly, however, the data is not being inserted into the database and no errors are appearing.  I've tested locally using MAMP and when the file is uploaded to the server it does not work.  Has anyone had this issue before on godaddy?  Below is my insert statement and form.

=================================

```
if ( $ax == "new" ) {

    $sql=<<<SQL

            INSERT INTO college (member_id, name, date_entered, date_completed, degree, professor, method, friends, memory_1)
            VALUES      (
                        '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}',  
                        '{$_GET['name']}', 
                        '{$_GET['date_entered']}', 
                        '{$_GET['date_completed']}',
                        '{$_GET['degree']}',
                        '{$_GET['professor']}',
                        '{$_GET['method']}',
                        '{$_GET['friends']}',
                        '{$_GET['memory_1']}'
                        )
```

SQL;

```
    echo $sql; exit;

    if(mysql_query( $sql ) or die ( "Insert failed." . mysql_error()) );

    header( "Location: education.php");
}
```

=====================

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ax" value="new">
    Institution<br><input type="text" name="name" /><br>
    Date Entered<br><input id="entered" type='text' name="date_entered" /><br>


    Date Completed<br><input id="completed" type='text' name="date_completed" /><br>
    Degree(s) Earned<br><input type="text" name="degree" /><br>
    Favorite Professor <br><input type="text" name="professor" /><br>
    Method of Study<br><select name="method" WIDTH="155" STYLE="width: 155px">
    <option value="Classroom">Classroom</option>
    <option value="Online">Online</option>
    </select><br>
    Friends<br><input type="text" name="friends" /><br>
    <br><br>
    Favorite Memory
    <br>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="memory_1"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all"/>
    </form>
```

===================

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Your form is sent as POST :

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
```

Which means you'll receive data, on the PHP side, in the `$_POST` super-global variable.

But your code is using $_GET.
*(Which should be populated only if you where usgin `action="get"` in your form)*

So, in your PHP script, you should probably use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Also, as a sidenote : your script screams [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) : you must escape data before injecting them in an SQL query !
About that, you can take a look at [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Pascal...Thanks for the reply.  I should have mentioned that I tried using $_GET, $_POST, and $_REQUEST.    None of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a register globals issue from the php.ini file.  For it to work w/ register globals off the ax flag looking like

```
if ( $ax == "new" )
```

It should be

```
if ( $post['ax'] = "new")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue using godaddy services.  Make sure and log in to your hosting plan and FTP.  Select the folder where this page resides and make certain the Privacy options are inheriting and otherwise properly set up.  If it's not, you can just get this same issue where its not working and there's no real code reason.  It needs reset every time you use the FTP manager on the web.  Using FileZilla to upload the files you've edited does not seem to trigger the issue.